# Pulling data from Microsoft Dynamics

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I use Microsoft Dynamics to manage daily incident tickets, daily requests and change requests.
I'd like to use their API and pull this information into a custom application to display them on a dashboard. 
Can you please point me in the correct direction?

Many thanks.

Comment: which Dynamics product? I guess Dynamics CRM, correct? version? language of your custom application?

Comment: my application is a Java application, It's Dynamics CRM Online (2013)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online (2013) - Get number of tickets via API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214062/microsoft-dynamics-crm-online-2013-get-number-of-tickets-via-api)