# Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online (2013) - Get number of tickets via API

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013

I use Dynamics CRM Online (2013) to manage daily incident tickets, daily requests and change requests. I'd like to use their API and pull this information into a custom application to display them on a dashboard.

Basically what I want to do is to be able to grab the number of open tickets using my application. Then it'll publish this information to elsewhere. It's a Java application running on a Windows server.

Can you please point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Let me google that for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602979.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MSDN lists a walkthrough (click here to see it)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602979.aspx) (it's related to CRM Online 2011, but since most of the info is still accurate I'd say it's worth a try) aimed exactly at connecting to CRM Online fom Java.

The prerequisites listed are

> Java SE SDK 1.6 update 23 or later
>
> Eclipse 3.7.x and above or NetBeans 6.9x or later
>
> Apache Axis 2 ver. 1.6.1
>
> Apache HTTP Components Client 4.1.3
>
> Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online

You're going to have to generate the classes (in .NET you use `crmsvcutil.exe`, it's roughly equivalent) and then you should be all set.

Comment: While yes that may work ... eventually - you should create a .Net proxy service/app that performs the desired functions from Java. The java example, if you read closely, is not intended for prod use. ;)